# Apply transition only on hover in and out

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, css-transitions

I have a following section of css:

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar:hover {
  width: 200px;
}

@media (width < 1080px) {
  .navbar {
    position: sticky;
    transition: none;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  .navbar:hover {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

It describes a navigation bar that is a sidebar when the viewport is bigger than 1080px. When I hover over it, it stretches to 200px. If the vieport becomes smaller than 1080px, the sidebar becomes horizontal navigation bar.

What I wanted to achieve was a smooth transition of stretching the sidebar on hover and on hover leave. At this moment this works as intended.

What I also wanted was snappy transition from sidebar to horizontal navigation bar and vice versa.
Unfortunately it works only partialy. Although I have achieved the snappy transition from sidebar to horizontal navigation bar, I cannot figure out how can I create snappy transition from horizontal navigation bar to sidebar.

I understand what is the problem here (when changing from horizontal navigation bar to sidebar the transtion is set again to 0.5s hence the animation) but I am struggling to figure out how to achieve two-way snappines from sidebar to navbar while maintaining the "hover-in-and-out" transition.

What would be the correct way of achieving such effect ?

Here is example of current state of the sidebar/navbar in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mz29afyh/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

I have no luck either with purely CSS and I think it might have no solution by just in CSS way because the transition is in effect all the time while window resizing.

When transition is from `transition:0.5s` to `transition:none` (screen < 1080, sidebar to navbar), it see a snappy transition because the *transition:none* is taking effect immediately. Same goes to when `transition:none` is remove (screen > 1080px, navbar to sidebar), the `transition:0.5s` is taking effect immediately and that's why it is a smooth transition for all properties.

But there is a workaround with the help of JS, if you don't mind. Here the result sample : https://jsfiddle.net/qog0s7wb/1/

The solution is taking from this article: [stop animations during window resize](https://css-tricks.com/stop-animations-during-window-resizing/). The idea is stop to the transition while window is resizing with a little help from timer function as shown below :

```
let resizeTimer;

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    $('.navbar').addClass('stop-transition');
  
  window.clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('remove')
    $('.navbar').removeClass('stop-transition');
  }, 100);
});
```

And an additional `.stop-transition` class :

```
.stop-transition {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

---

If you want to remain all transition smoothly, then it is simple, just remove the `transition: none;` when @media (width < 1080px).

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't do what I want to achieve. I want no transition when changing from sidebar to navbar and vice versa.

Comment: woops, sorry, misunderstand about your statement. it can be done actually, let me reorder the CSS. basically is (1) when screen < 1080, horizontal bar, (2) when screen > 1080, sidebar with hover-in-out effect, (3) horizontal to sidebar and vice versa need to be instant, right ?

Comment: Yep, that was a solution that I was looking for, thank you !